# ECSlidingViewController previous topviewcontroller

Tags: ios7, ecslidingviewcontroller

Currently I am replacing the ECSlidingViewController.topviewcontroller to go to a other viewcontroller. But Now I want the previous viewcontroller to return to the last screen.

So I am on a list and want to see the details. The ECSlidingViewController.topviewcontroller is called and the nieuw uiviewcontroller is set to the topviewcontroller. Now I want to return to the list. How can this been done?

Comment: I currently always pushing to a viewcontroller that refreshed the topviewcontroller.

Answer (score 0):

I currently always pushing to a viewcontroller that refreshed the topviewcontroller.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create a bar button item in the child view controller and set an IBAction:

```
- (IBAction)revealMenu:(id)sender {

    [self.slidingViewController anchorTopViewTo:ECRight];

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I solved it otherwise. But thanks for your time.